# Qt Android: Pressing "Done" does not hide the keyboard

Tags: android, c++, qt, keyboard, qt5

When I write into a line edit using the Android keyboard, and I press the "Done" button (screenshot below), the keyboard does not disappear. This happens even in a newly created project with just a line edit (I tested it).

How can I make "Done" to hide the keyboard?

Please note that I am looking for a developer solution (i.e. programming, not user oriented) and a native way (i.e. C++/Qt, not Java).

I'm using Qt 5.2.0.

[image]

Comment: Based on the two answers below, I would suggest to clarify your question just in case even though I gave a +1 myself. I would not have thought this is necessary, but apparently it is. :-)

Comment: OK, but how? I already write "Qt Android" in the title. Maybe change it to "(NOT Java) Qt Android: Pressing “Done” does not hide the keyboard"

Comment: I tried to edit your question to reflect our discussion. Please feel free to revert it if you do not see it as an improvement.

Comment: Found this for you, hope it will work! http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32152/

Comment: @sashoalm, has my answer been useful?

Comment: What is the meaning of "native"? 
If we talk about Android development, perhaps native means Java, not C++.

Comment: @FernandoPelliccioni Well the C++ API is called by Google the NDK, aka. Native Development Kit. By native, I think they mean native to the **processor**.

Comment: Right, native is because it is compiled to "native" processor code instead of intermediate code.
But in our case, "native way solution" maybe could be confused.
The "natural way" of making Android applications is using Java.
(Besides, I'm a C++ programmer, Java seems to me an horrible language)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call the [QInputMethod::hide()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qinputmethod.html#hide) slot.

C++ Solution

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), QGuiApplication::inputMethod(), SLOT(hide()));
```

QML Solution

```
TextInput {
    Keys.onEnterPressed: {
        //...
        Qt.inputMethod.hide()
    }
    Keys.onReturnPressed: {
        //...
        Qt.inputMethod.hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: It is strange... QML solution worked for me, but now it doesn't. The system output is: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of undefined". Any ideas?